# Can I print the full path of a keystroke or mouse click in C# console Application

Tags: c#, input, rpa, uipath

I'm working with the RPA software UIPath.  UIPath simulates keystrokes and mouse clicks.  What I want to do is differentiate between when I open notepad and type a keystroke manually as the user and when I run my UIPath robot and have the bot type into notepad.

The reason is I am trying to filter out the difference between a user manually typing and the UIPath bot typing.  I need to do this for another piece of software that's running that is monitoring keystrokes and mouse clicks.  I want the software to not record keystrokes and mouse clicks from the bot and would like to be able to find the execution path of the UIPath bot so I can set up a filter.

My solutions is I'd like to run some C# code and have the console log the different execution paths between me typing manually in the keyboard and then compare it with UIPath bot typing.  I'm unsure of how to do this and all I can do is just record in the console if 'a','b','7' etc... was typed, but not exactly the path that was taken for 'a', 'b', '7', etc to be typed.  Any help or other suggestions on how to solve this problem would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Not sure if there's a direct way to tell whether the input is done by a user or a robot, but you could measure it indirectly (by characters per minute). Example: an average person is unlikely to type more than 4, so everything above that could be a bot (note that UiPath could just wait for random intervals between typing, so there's no 100%). In that case a keylogger could help, all you'd have to do is to parse its log file (assuming the logger provides a timestamp between major events, such as focusing and closing an application).

Comment: How about simply checking if the process is running? I.e. `UiRobot.exe`. You can check this programmatically. The idea behind RPA is that it 'takes control' of the desktop, hence you, the user, shouldn't interfere. At the very least, if `UiRobot.exe` is not running, it means a user is typing.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps you can code to detect if a keyboard or mouse input is simulated or not :

1. You need to capture low-level keyboard and mouse events using [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) i.e. 
   `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and `WH_MOUSE_LL`
2. The hook procedure for WH_KEYBOARD_LL will receive [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagkbdllhookstruct) structure and for `WH_MOUSE_LL` it will be [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmsllhookstruct) structure.
3. [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagkbdllhookstruct) has flags field . If `LLKHF_INJECTED` is set for this field , it would mean that this keyboard input was injected. Keyboard events produced by driver doesn't have this flag set.
4. Similarly [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmsllhookstruct) has flags field. If `LLKHF_INJECTED` is set for this field , it would mean that this mouse input was injected. Mouse events produced by driver doesn't have this flag set.

These flag are set on windows kernel level and it is not possible to change them using winapi. I had read about this technique being used by anti-cheat system for games in the book [Practical Video Game Bots](https://www.amazon.in/Practical-Video-Game-Bots-Automating-ebook/dp/B07GRM2G5Q/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1539022947&sr=8-1&keywords=practical%20video%20game%20bots). Please note that if you use C# library like [globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook), this data might not be available in the `MouseEventExtArgs/KeyboardEventArgsEx`  that is being passed to callback function. Please check any third party library you might be using for availability of this data.